# Relation between monomorphicity and faithfulness?

Tags: category-theory, functors, monomorphisms

I'm a beginner in cat theory, so this may seem straight-forward, but I didn't manage to untangle anything by trying to write it calmly...

This question arised from the fact that in **Cat**, whose objetcts are small cats and arrows functors betweens those cats, the isomorphisms are precisely the isomorphisms of categories (isomorphic functors).

Also in **Cat**, there is a notion of *monomorphicity* that applies to *functors*, since they are precisely the *morphisms* of **Cat**.

But we also have a notion of *faithfulness* of a functor. In this special case of morphisms of **Cat**, how do these notions relate one to each other ?

The real question is : if a functor between small cats is interpreted as a *morphism* of **Cat**, how to translate (in terms of functors) the notion of monomorphicity ?

And since we're at it, how to do the same with the notion of epimorphicity ?

Thanks already for the kind answers !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What it means for a functor $F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ to be faithful is that, for each $A,B \in \mathrm{ob}(\mathcal{C})$, the function $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(A,B) \to \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{D}}(FA, FB)$ is an injection (i.e. a monomorphism in $\mathbf{Set}$). Note that this condition only talks about the morphisms of $\mathcal{D}$, so for instance $F$ could in theory send every object of $\mathcal{C}$ to a single object of $\mathcal{D}$ and still be faithful.

On the other hand, the monomorphisms $F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ are precisely the *embeddings*, which are functors that are faithful *and* injective on objects, so that distinct objects of $\mathcal{C}$ are sent to distinct objects of $\mathcal{D}$. So every monomorphism in $\mathbf{Cat}$ is a faithful functor, but not every faithful functor is a monomorphism.

Epimorphisms in $\mathbf{Cat}$ are a bit trickier to pin down, so I don't think the relationship between epimorphisms and full functors will be quite as easy to describe.